# How to create a matrix for a set of data that keeps changing

Tags: python, matlab

I have a set of LiDAR data from RTMaps software that keeps changing but is always a multiple of 6. I want to reshape this data to create multiple 1x6 matrices of that data so that Simulink can read the data. Can anyone please help?
[LiDAR data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGtwC.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!'

Answer (score 0):

You could just take the data input as a numpy array and then use the [resize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html#numpy.resize) property and shape it as you wish and then maybe pass it to your function, keep repeating this step till you have read all your data.
Although this is not enough information to begin with but what I am suggesting would look something like :

```
//assuming you have imported numpy and other requirements
//take input from the file
//iterate over it and store results in a numpy array
//call transform data on this array
def transform_data(numpy_array):
    //resize into desired size
    pass_converted(numpay_array)
def pass_converted(n_array):
    //do your thing
```

PS : I know that my naming convention could be a bit better and I could've finished this in fewer lines of code but this gives a more clear understanding.